# Python Pycryptodome AES-GCM encryption code performance improvement

Tags: python, aes-gcm, pycryptodome

I am having around 19G of data which I am doing tar and then encrypt. I use below code to do the job.

```
from subprocess import call
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
import sys

cmd = ["tar","--acls","--selinux","-czPf","./out.tar.gz","./src"]
proc = call(cmd)
data = open("./out.tar.gz", "rb").read()
key = get_random_bytes(32)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM)
ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)

out = open("./out.bin", "wb")
[out.write(x) for x in (cipher.nonce, tag, ciphertext)]
out.close()
```

I am using HP Gen10 hardware with 48 CPU cores and 128G memory and 1800.3 GB HDD space. Only one core is being utilized for almost 100% and memory usage is around 43%. The overall process is taking more than a day.
I look for the ways to improve the performance in the above code.

I have made significant improvements in the code after **SquareRootOfTwentyThree** comments:

```
from subprocess import call
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
import StringIO

key = get_random_bytes(32)

def readLargeFile(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data

cmd = ["tar","--acls","--selinux","-czPf","./out.tar.gz","./src"]
call(cmd)

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM)
ciphertext = []

for data in readLargeFile("./out.tar.gz"):
    ciphertext.append(cipher.encrypt(data))

out = open("./out.bin", "wb")
[out.write(x) for x in (cipher.nonce, cipher.digest(), b"".join(ciphertext))]
out.close()

file_in = open("./out.bin", "rb")
nonce, tag, ciphertext = [file_in.read(x) for x in (16, 16, -1)]
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce)
#data = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)
data = []
for buf in StringIO.StringIO(ciphertext).read(1024):
    data.append(cipher.decrypt(buf))
cipher.verify(tag)
with open("./dst/out.tar.gz", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b''.join(data))
cmd = ["tar","-xzPf","./dst/out.tar.gz","-C","./dst"]
proc = call(cmd)
```

Encrypt is successful but **decrypt's verify()** is causing *ValueError: MAC check failed*
Note: I am using PyCryptodome v3.6.6

Somehow I successfully proceeded with **decryption** and below is my latest code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,call
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
import StringIO,io,tarfile
import os,sys
import datetime

print "*** Encryption Starts *** " + str(datetime.datetime.now())
key = get_random_bytes(32)

def readLargeFile(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data

cmd = ["tar --acls --selinux -czPf /nfs/out.tar.gz ./encrypt_disk/src/*"]
call(cmd, shell=True)

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM)
ciphertext = []

for data in readLargeFile("/nfs/out.tar.gz"):
    ciphertext.append(cipher.encrypt(data))

out = open("/nfs/out.bin", "wb")
[out.write(x) for x in (cipher.nonce, cipher.digest(), b"".join(ciphertext))]
out.close()
print "*** Encryption Ends *** " + str(datetime.datetime.now())


print "*** Decryption Starts *** " + str(datetime.datetime.now())
file_in = open("/nfs/out.bin", "rb")
nonce, tag, ciphertext = [file_in.read(x) for x in (16, 16, -1)]
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce)
tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=StringIO.StringIO(cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)), mode='r|*')
os.chdir("/nfs/dst")
tar.extractall(path='.')
print "*** Decryption Ends *** " + str(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCM is hard (though not impossible) to parallelize. Still, on my 3-year x86 laptop (with AESNI and CLMUL accelerated instructions) I do get 150 MB/s with PyCryptodome's GCM. That is only 2 minutes for 19GB, not a day! I used the following toy code:

```
data = os.urandom(1024*1024)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM)
for _ in range(1024):
    cipher.encrypt(data)
tag = cipher.digest()
```

The code is not directly usable for your use case, but it indicates that there might be an issue with you encrypting the full 19GB at once. Perhaps, you should instead break up the processing in chunks.

Some other comments:

- Use a profiler to identify where your program takes the most time. It might not be where you think it is (e.g. what about the `tar` step?).
- Ensure you are using the latest version of PyCryptodome (3.6.6), since CLMUL acceleration [was added only recently](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/changelog.html).
- GCM can only encrypt 256GB at most - you are not that far from that with 19GB.

Comment: Thank you for your tips `@SquareRootOfTwentyThree`. I have made some improvements in my code and posted it here. However, I am getting MAC error at the `decrypt verify()` part.

Comment: The issue has been resolved in the latest PyCryptodome-3.7.0 release https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/changelog.html#resolved-issues

Comment: According to NIST800-38D GCM recommendations, the maximum plaintext length is much lower than your suggestion: len(P) ≤ 2^39-256, which is around 64GB, not 256GB. I'd be interested to know where this 256GB number came from.